# Python script to check if android device is connected to internet

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, adb

I am writing a python script to check if my android device is connected to internet. I am trying to do the following in adb shell:

1. busybox telnet 173.194.33.97 80
2. GET / HTTP/1.0

The output is:
- HTTP/1.0 200 OK

I care only about HTTP/1.0 200 OK, to check the internet connectivity.

I tried to use netcat in python but I don't have a very good experience to implement it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured out that using the following command will return HTTP/1.0 200 OK, but I couldn't put it in a python code.  (adb shell "echo 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | nc 173.194.33.103 80")

Comment: If you have figured out the answer for your own question, it is strongly encouraged to add it as an answer here.

Comment: @kartikg3 Thank you for your comment. I still having difficulties "Pythonizing" it. It is hard to deal with double/single quotes. I am working now on fixing it and later I will post a python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the Python script is:

```
cmd = "adb shell \"echo \'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n\' | nc 173.194.33.103 80\""
p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
#The output will be "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" OR "HTTP/2.0 200 OK"
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    if line.rstrip().startswith('HTTP/') and line.rstrip().endswith('200 OK'):
        print '\nFOUND IT: ' + line.rstrip()
        wifi_flag = True
        break
```